# How to subtract contents of IntegerField of one table from another in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

**How it works:** When I add a product to the **Bouquet** table, in the *CompositionOfTheBouquetInline* class, I can select an object from the **Flower** table and select the number of flowers.

**For example,**

- there is a "Rose" flower in the **Flower** table, *stock* = 10
- there is a bouquet "Bouquet of roses" in the **Bouquet** table, *stock* = 1
- select the "Rose" flower in the amount of 5 and save, in the **CompositionOfTheBouquet** table

**What is going to happen:**

- flower "Rose" is now *stock* = 5, in the **Flower** table

**Formula:**

- Flower.stock = Flower.stock - (CompositionOfTheBouquet.count * Bouquet.stock)

**models.py**

```
class Flower(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Bouquet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class CompositionOfTheBouquet(models.Model):
    flower = models.ForeignKey(
        Flower, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    bouquet = models.ForeignKey(
        Bouquet, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

**admin.py**

```
from .models import Flower, Bouquet, CompositionOfTheBouquet


class CompositionOfTheBouquetInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CompositionOfTheBouquet

@admin.register(Flower)
class Flower(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Bouquet)
class Bouquet(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CompositionOfTheBouquetInline, ]
```

**What you need to do:** When adding a flower and its quantity, you need to remove this number of flowers and save it in the **Flower** table, *stock* column.

**Important:** calculations should take place when adding a Bouquet through the admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to override the save behavior of the `CompositionOfTheBouquet` model.

If this should not be the default behavior every time you create/update the `CompositionOfTheBouquet` model, look into using [proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) to override the `save()` method only on the proxy class.

This could also be achieved by using signals, but according to [this antipattern](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html), it's better to avoid them.

**Note:** assuming `count` property is the number of flowers in one bouquet.

```py
class CompositionOfTheBouquet(models.Model):
    flower = models.ForeignKey(
        Flower, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    bouquet = models.ForeignKey(
        Bouquet, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)


    # Override __init__ method to keep track of what changed (saves a trip to DB)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._initial_count = self.count


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        # After saving the `CompositionOfTheBouqet` model, update the `Flower` 
        # model using the formula you provided with a small change. Using the
        # count_diff to update the number of flower only by the changed count.
        # This is needed for update scenarios. Also, when you reduce number
        # of flowers in the composition, the flower stock will increase
        count_diff = self.count - self._initial_count
        if count_dict != 0:  # Only update the flower if count has changed
            self.flower.stock = self.flower.stock - (count_diff * self.bouquet.stock)
            self.flower.save()
```

PS. - a small note on the logic here. If you select too many flowers, you will get a database error for setting a negative number in the `PositiveIntegerField`. This should be handled by some validation, I guess.